# WPF Animation Error on Deploy

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm getting the error below when using the release version of a WPF project.
The error is related with a ListView that I have.
For this Listview/ I use a Blend FluidMoveBehavior inside  section

```
<ListView x:Name="SearchListBox" Margin="4,100,4,4"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppsCollectionViewSource}}"
              BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <ei:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                        <ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                            <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                        <ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                            <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </ei:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                    </ei:FluidMoveBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

At the UserControl.Resources I have a Trigger that triggers an animation (scale) when IsMouseOver.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0 0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                            To="1.28" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                            To="1.28" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                            To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                            To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In Debug no errors, when doing Release version, I get, some times, application crashes when resizing the Window. I attached VS to the process and I got:

**Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'RenderTransform.ScaleX'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.**

Any Ideas how to solve this? I have no codebehind and all declarations are made inside XAML.
If I use only FluidMoveBehavior or only the IsMouseOver the problem appears to go away.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I found out that the problem occurs if I resize the Window and mouse over the rectangles inside ListView while the FluidMoveBehavior is still animating/re-ordering the ListView Items. So the problem appears to be in the Trigger IsMouseOver (I also confirm this by commenting the Trigger IsMouseOver code section).
The solution may pass by canceling the IsMouseOver event if the FluidMoveBehavior is still animating.
Anyone knows how to do this in XAML code?

Comment: You might want to try and modify the trigger to an event trigger for MouseEnter and MouseLeave. That way the animation is only started once.

Comment: The IsMouseOver is to run when moving the mouse over the item every time the user overs it.